# Resizing the CSS shape elements with browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap. I have created some shapes using CSS and would like it to be resized along with browser. I have included the min.css.

In larger screen, it looks like this, I want the same layout

[image]

I have created a square and two circles. When I resize, I get it stacked one below the other. I would like to have the same layout I see in large devices in mobile too, but I cant get it to shrink.

html:

```
<div id="mainpage" class="container">   
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2" id="sqr">
                </div>  
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row" id="circle1"></div>
                    <div class="row" id="circle2"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
css:

#sqr
{
    height: 400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: red;
}
#circle1
{

    width:14em;
    height:14em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#circle2
{
    width:14em;
    height:14em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the circles to resize use width: 100%;

```
#sqr {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
#circle1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. But I want the whole set up to shrink. I was wondering if Bootstrap could provide something as it helps in responsiveness

Comment: Hey updated my anwser for you, also here is a link to the bootstrap grid. this will help make site responsive https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. It doesn't work like I want it to. I need the same design, but a smaller version which fits in a mobile device. Since I've constructed my shapes using CSS, I'm finding it difficult to. If I had used an image, I could just use img-thumbnail which would have placed itself properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove fixed values for height and width. They will always be this big.

Check out instead : max-height:400px and min-height:100px / min-height:25%;

max-width:400px;
max-width:400px;

```
#sqr{
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

EDIT : 
Check if You got bootstrap css/js properly linked.

```
<div class="border row">
<div class="border col-sm-6">
<div id="circle1"></div>
</div>
<div class="border col-sm-6">
<div id="circle2"></div>
</div>   
</div>
```

AND js fiddle : 
jsfiddle.net/cxcgL5s1

Comment: That didn't work either.  I've seen examples where they make it shrink along with browser size. I was hoping Bootstrap could help.